# Latitude and Longitude to pixel-value in GDAL

Tags: c#, geolocation, tiff, gdal, geotiff

I'm trying to read a GeoTIFF with one band which stores a value between 0 and 3 ( 255 is no maks ). My Goal is to write a little program which takes in a latitude/longitude and returns the fitting pixel value at the geocoordinate in the geotiff.

I downloaded it from here : https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/QQHCIK
And if you wanna take a look at it... heres the download link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/104De_YQN1V8tSbj2uhIPO0FfowjnInnX/view?usp=sharing

However, my code does not work. I cant tell you what is wrong, it just outputs the wrong pixel value every damn time. I guess either my geocordinate to pixel transformation is wrong or theres a huge logic mistake.

This was my first try, it prints the wrong value for the geo-coordinate.
Furthermore it crashes with some geocoordinates, a negative longitude makes it crashes because this will make `pixelY` negative which causes an exception in the raster method.

```
            GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
            var tif = "C:\\Users\\Lars\\Downloads\\pnv_biome.type_biome00k_c_1km_s0..0cm_2000..2017_v0.1.tif";
            var lat = 51.0;
            var lon = 8.3;
            using (var image = Gdal.Open(tif, Access.GA_ReadOnly)) {

                var bOneBand = image.GetRasterBand(1);
                var width = bOneBand.XSize;
                var height = bOneBand.YSize;
                
                // Geocoordinate ( lat, lon ) to pixel in the tiff ? 
                var geoTransform = new double[6];
                image.GetGeoTransform(geoTransform);
                Gdal.InvGeoTransform(geoTransform, geoTransform);
                
                var bOne = new int[1];
                Gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(geoTransform, lat, lon, out var pixelXF, out var pixelYF);

                var pixelX = (int)Math.Floor(pixelXF);
                var pixelY = (int)Math.Floor(pixelYF);
                
                // Read pixel 
                bOneBand.ReadRaster(pixelX, pixelY, 1, 1, bOne, 1, 1,0,0);
                Console.WriteLine(bOne[0]); // bOne[0] contains wrong data
            }
```

My second attempt looks like the following... but also outputs the wrong pixel value for the given coordinates. It also crashes with some geocoordinates.

```
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
            var tif = "C:\\Users\\Lars\\Downloads\\pnv_biome.type_biome00k_c_1km_s0..0cm_2000..2017_v0.1.tif";
            var lat = 24.7377; // 131.5847
            var lon = 131.5847;
            
            using (var image = Gdal.Open(tif, Access.GA_ReadOnly)) {

                var bOneBand = image.GetRasterBand(1);
                var bOne = new int[1];
                
                // Spatial reference to transform latlng to map coordinates... from python code
                var point_srs = new SpatialReference("");
                var file_srs = new SpatialReference(image.GetProjection());
                point_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326);
                point_srs.SetAxisMappingStrategy(AxisMappingStrategy.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER);
           
                var mapCoordinates = new double[2]{ lat, lon};
                var transform = new CoordinateTransformation(point_srs, file_srs);
                transform.TransformPoint(mapCoordinates);
                
                // Map coordinates to pixel coordinates ? 
                var geoTransform = new double[6];
                image.GetGeoTransform(geoTransform);
                Gdal.InvGeoTransform(geoTransform, geoTransform);
                
                Gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(geoTransform, mapCoordinates[0], mapCoordinates[1], out var pixelXF, out var pixelYF);
                var pixelX = (int)pixelXF;
                var pixelY = (int)pixelYF;
                
                bOneBand.ReadRaster(pixelX, pixelY, 1, 1, bOne, 1, 1, 0,0);
                Console.WriteLine(bOne[0]);  // bOne[0] contains wrong value
            }
```

What is wrong with my code, why does it output the wrong pixel value ?
Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are using lat/lon where it should be lon/lat? It would be helpful if you printed some values such as `mapCoordinates`.

Here is how you can do this with R, for comparison:

```
library(terra)
r = rast("pnv_biome.type_biome00k_c_1km_s0..0cm_2000..2017_v0.1.tif")
xy = cbind(c(8.3, 131.5847), c(51.0, 24.7377))
extract(r, xy)
#  pnv_biome.type_biome00k_c_1km_s0..0cm_2000..2017_v0.1
#1                                                     9
#2                                                    NA
```

And the zero-based row/col numbers

```
rowColFromCell(r, cellFromXY(r, xy)) - 1
#     [,1]  [,2]
#[1,] 4364 22596
#[2,] 7515 37390
```

And you can use `describe` (a.k.a. GDALinfo) to get some metadata. E.g.

```
d = describe("pnv_biome.type_biome00k_c_1km_s0..0cm_2000..2017_v0.1.tif")
d[50]
# [1] "Band 1 Block=43200x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray"
```

Comment: Damn why is this so easy in R and so hart in c# ? I just switched the coordinates to try that... didnt worked, it just crashed because it calculated a pixel value below zero which band.ReadRaster() didnt liked :/ I assume i calculate the pixel position the wrong way... but i have no experience in this topic and there nearly no resources about that. My code above is heavly inspired by the python code examples i found

Comment: Your answer was actually quite helpfull, but only solved half the problem. It doesnt crash anymore, but still returns wrong values sometimes or almost always. But when i load in my geotiff into a geotiff viewer, it shows me that the tiff works.

Comment: Figured it out, there were two problems... the issue you discovered with switched latitude and longitude values AND... the bands data is byte, not integer. It works now flawless, thanks for your help !

Comment: Good to hear that. See my expanded answer for `describe` (GDALinfo) to get that type of metadata.